# A user just can a one comment, What will be the logic?

Tags: django, django-templates

I already made a review form where user can give their feedback on the service. The form works perfectly, and data is also stored in the database. There is a rating star options as well. ***Now I just want to make a system where the user just can do one review.*** If a user did a review the review form won't show to the user. Now, what should I do? and What'll be the logic?

***models.py:***

```
class Frontend_Rating(models.Model):
    USer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="frontend_rating")
    Rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Feedback = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

***template:***

```
<form action="frontend_ratings/" class="mt-3" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="radio-toolbar d-flex justify-content-center ">
                        <input type="radio" id="one_star" name="frontend_ratting" value="1" checked>
                        <label for="one_star" class="mx-1">1 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

                        <input type="radio" id="two_star" name="frontend_ratting" value="2">
                        <label for="two_star" class="mx-1">2 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

                        <input type="radio" id="three_star" name="frontend_ratting" value="3">
                        <label for="three_star" class="mx-1">3 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

                        <input type="radio" id="four_star" name="frontend_ratting" value="4">
                        <label for="four_star" class="mx-1">4 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>

                        <input type="radio" id="five_star" name="frontend_ratting" value="5">
                        <label for="five_star" class="mx-1">5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- feedback area-->
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <textarea style="font-size: small;" maxlength="250" name="frontend_feedback"
                            placeholder="Share your experience in 250 charecters...."
                            class="col-10 mt-2 hireme_textarea btn montserrat text-left d-block" required
                            rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn singUpBtn col-10 submit_btn_sing_up_in sing_up_js1"
                            id="message">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
```

Comment: If a user can only do one review, you should make `OneToOne` relation, that is `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Instead of ForeignKey? Oke, I'll change. Now, what can be relevant logic in templates?